# Compact Git repository with history depth

Tags: git

In Git, there is a command `git clone --depth=<depth>` to retrieve historical data only specific length. there are also a command to gather more historical data by use `git fetch --depth=<depth>`.

How about when we want to free some spaces from large repository? I know that we may use `git gc` or `git prune` but are there other way to specific like `--depth=<depth>` to reduce number of commit store in local repository? AND it also should keep SHA1 to be able continue to working with it.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to:

- delete entirely the current local repo
- `git clone --depth=n /url/of/remote/repo`

That would clone the last n commits, while allowing fetch/pull/psuh to still work with the remote repo.

since Git 2.5, you can [fetch a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309), but unless that commit is the latest one (which is like a `git clone --depth=1`), that would not allo for fetch/pull/push.

The other approach to make sure a given local repo is as lean as possible is to use a [combination of gc/prune/repack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720432/6309):

```
git gc --aggressive
git repack -Ad       # kills in-pack garbage
git prune --progress # kills loose garbage
```