# Git push fails over Wifi with broken pipe error - works fine over Ethernet

Tags: git, macos, networking, ssh, macos-high-sierra

I'm working on OSX 10.13. Git push fails using command line and SourceTree with the following error:

*packet_write_wait: Connection to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly*

This error only ever occurs over Wifi. If I connect via Ethernet, the push always succeeds without error. I have tried with two seperate wireless networks and it fails on both.

My best guess is that OSX is blocking something on port 22 over wireless that it otherwise allows over an Ethernet connection, but I have no idea what would be doing that. Can anyone suggest what might be going on?

Comment: Does this always happen, or is it intermittent or perhaps infrequent?

Comment: Happens consistently @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I don't think it's blocking your port, but rather your IP address.  My guess is that it somehow can't see behind the WiFi.

Comment: What's 'it' in this scenario? @TimBiegeleisen You mean OSX?

Comment: Just saying that your actual IP may somehow be getting masked by the wireless router.

Comment: This seems to be a network configuration issue, making it off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I feel it might be an ssh/git issue as others on my network successfully push to the same repos over the same wifi. In any case there are lots of instances of people reporting this issue, but no solid solution. Thought it might be useful to the developer community here if a solution was proposed.

Comment: @Gerard Were you ever able to determine the cause?  Having the same issue.

Comment: This issue explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262847/7019580