# git: Delete files and directories from all history but keep all branches (not just the master branch)

Tags: git

I tried this [tutorial](https://blog.ostermiller.org/git-remove-from-history) to delete some sensitive files and directories from my Git history. However, at the end, my new repository only had 1 branch: the master branch.

How is possible to delete files and directories from Git history while keeping all branches?

Thank you!

commands I used (from the tutorial):

```
cd /tmp 

git clone https://MY_GIT_REPOSITORY.git workingrepo

cd workingrepo

for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do

git branch --track ${branch##*/} $branch 

done 

git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch FILE_LIST' --prune-empty -f -- --all 

rm -rf .git/refs/original/ 

git reflog expire --expire=now --all 

git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Comment: I don’t think so. Branches would keep old insecure commits from being deleted.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  Not even possible to do it branch by branch?

Comment: So you want to filter out files from commits and then move the branches?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  I want to keep all of the branches, but remove these specific files from the history of each of the branches.

Comment: Show *all* the commands you used (complete with output if possible).

Comment: @torek  here you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've posted, that *should* have worked.  The:

> ```
> for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do
>     git branch --track ${branch##*/} $branch
> done
> ```

sequence should create a branch for each branch in the original repository.  If you examine the set of branches afterward, you should see the right names.  (This method is a bit clumsy compared to just using `git clone --mirror` for the initial clone, but sometimes there are reasons to avoid `--mirror`, which makes a bare clone.)

The filter-branch operation (lines split for posting purposes here):

> ```
> git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat \
>     --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch FILE_LIST' \
>     --prune-empty -f -- --all
> ```

should then operate on all branches (`--all` at the end); the index filter will remove a file named `FILE_LIST` (presumably this is short for the actual list of files), and you should see a lot of progress messages plus a list of branch names that `filter-branch` updated.

You can examine the branch names again at this point; they should be the same names as before (though the commit hashes to which they point may, and usually will, differ).

The remaining commands do some cleanup.  The `--aggressive` is unnecessary (see [Linus Torvalds' explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28721047/1256452)) but using `git gc` or re-cloning are appropriate for discarding the unwanted objects.  These will have no effect on branch names, so those two particular points are where to check why something has gone wrong.