# how to delete a branch completely from origin so that the repo size also decreases

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repo which has branches like branch-a, branch-b, branch-c.
Now, in branch-b I have mistakenly uploaded a big file (200mb).
Now the overall repo has exceeded to 230mb.
Whenever I do git clone, I am downloading 230mb when I only require 30mb of data.
I also deleted this branch both locally and in remote.
This branch has not merged with master, and its commits are of no use.

How can I reduce my repo size as if this branch had never existed?
I do not want the commits to be rewritten.
To delete the branch I have followed:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D branch-b
git push origin --delete branch-b
```

I am new to git so, if I could get exact steps to do this would be very helpful, I am scared of messing up the remote.

Comment: *How can I reduce my repo size as if this branch had never existed? I do not want the commits to be rewritten.* You may not have a choice: if the file exists in some commit that is [reachable](http://think-like-a-git.net/), you must rewrite history so that this is no longer the case. After that, you wait: Git will eventually "garbage collect" the unwanted commits and the repository will shrink. Cloning will generally go faster right away as clones won't pick up any unreachable commits.

Comment: Thanks @torek that is relieving. When will git perform garbage collection?

Comment: The time of a future GC is not predictable. You can force one immediately if it's important (see @VonC's answer) but you'll need to expire any reflog entries that refer to the commit, too. The reflogs are a safety feature that let you get commits back if you want them. Reflog entries themselves eventually expire, so this "get commits back" has a time limit, but the actual expiration is merely an "at least" (at least 30 days, at least 90 days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your local repo, you can try (as I [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720432/6309))

```sh
git gc
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

You can also, as commented, clone the remote repository to check if the size has changed.

In both case (local gc, or clone), apply the tool [**`github/git-sizer`**](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to check what element is still taking space in your repository.